# Spring message bundle issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got a spring-security setup in my web-app. I want to replace some messages of spring security with my custom messages i.e.

Instead of `Bad Credentials` I want `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials` to have value `invalid username or password, please try again`

This is my spring setup :

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages"/>
<!-- Tried this as well <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties"/> -->
<property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

And I have created folder in the `WEB-INF` called `messages`. Inside this folder there is file called `messages.properties`. Inside this file is one line :

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=invalid username or password, please try again
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update :

This servlet-context is defined in the web xml :

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Problem solved, moved the messageSource bean definition to another context.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks right. Try to get the message using spring message tag in order to check if the problem is with your configuration or with the security message:

```
<spring:message code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials" />
```

If this does work, problem is not with your configuration (that looks fine for me).

Anyway, try to put your messages files in the classpath (source folder) and this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Also, check that the bean is being declared in a application context file that Spring is aware of.

Comment: but I see my context has loaded `INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]`

Comment: Try putting your message files in your source dir (without /messsages/ folder)